Using special characters in a label using the neo4j javascript driver
I am trying to create a node with a label that starts with a numeric character. I was following the documentation and other stack overflow answers, but I was never able to get this to work.
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/naming/#symbolic-names-escaping-rules
I have tried multiple different solution from inlining backticks with \` and wrapping different parts of the query with backticks.
const escapedName = escapeLabel(uniqueIdentifier);
const queryInsert = `
MERGE (w:example:${escapedName}) 
RETURN w
  `;

function escapeLabel(label: string): string {
  if (/^[0-9]/.test(label)) {
    return "`" + label + "`";
  }
  return label;
}

When I console log the query insert I see the backticks
{
  queryInsert: "\n  MERGE (w:example::`9tV3G7nWMnduftSTQtzB4xpHK4iz1`) \n  RETURN w\n  ",
}

But the error message says
Neo4jError: Invalid input '::': expected ")", "WHERE", "{" or a parameter (line 2, column 17 (offset: 19))
"  MERGE (w:example::`9tV3G7nWMnduftSTQtzB4xpHK4iz1`)"

If I changed the input to a label that doesn't start with a numeric character, it all works fine.
-- Update --
I think storing so many variables in a label name is non optimal, and I should instead store it as properties. This might be a non-issue but still interesting

From the name, I am guessing queryInsert is inserted into to some other Cypher snippet. If I am correct, show that query snippet.

Like the error says, :: is invalid. This is valid:
MERGE (w:example:`9tV3G7nWMnduftSTQtzB4xpHK4iz1`)
RETURN w


That was a typo, still failed.

{
  queryInsert: "\n  MERGE (w:example:`9tV3G7nWMnduftSTQtzB4xpHK4iz1`) \n  RETURN w\n  ",
}
INSERTED
615 |     };
616 |     return Result;
617 | }());
618 | _a = Symbol.toStringTag;
619 | function captureStacktrace() {
620 |     var error = new Error('');
                          ^
Neo4jError: Invalid input ':': expected ")", "WHERE", "{" or a parameter (line 2, column 23 (offset: 29))
"      MATCH (w:wallet:solana:9tV3G7nWMnduftSTQtzB4xpHK4iz1)"
                             ^


The error is a little hard to decode because the carat pointing at the error is not lined up. But I can see this is invalid: MATCH (w:wallet:solana:9tV3G7nWMnduftSTQtzB4xpHK4iz1) Put that third label in backticks and see if it works. Because what I posted in my answer is definitely OK.
